# Routing: Resolving parameters and conditioning them

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there any way I can automatically resolve parameters before they are handed to the controller?

For example, currently, I have a controller that looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{group}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Unbundle(string group)
{
    return Ok(db.Find(group));
}
```

Given the route parameter is denoted `{group}`, is there any feature in dotnet that allows me to intercept the id, look up the entity in my database and hand the controller the entity instead, like so:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("{group}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Unbundle(Group group)
{
    return Ok(group);
}
```

I looked into the `DynamicRouteValueTransformer,` but it looks like it is used to manipulate which controller and action get selected depending on the input.

#### Bonus Question

Furthermore, I'd like to verify that the logged-in user has access to the given group. Is there a specific way to do this without having to do so in every controller action?

Comment: Keyword ```middleware``` and ```ActionFilter``` and [authentication-filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

Comment: You can implement action filters to intercept https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Personally, I would avoid doing this. You're starting to tightly couple your data layer with the public API. I would just accept the string as the parameter and look up the value in a service layer.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you for your suggestion. To me, this just seems like a tedious code that has to be repeated. I understand the architectural implications that this has.

Comment: Tedious code that is repeated where though? If it's in the service layer, there is no repeat.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that everything is tied up to repositories, the dependency is pretty limited at this point.

Comment: @DavidG I would still have to look up the record in every controller action, no?

Comment: Well, I would pass the string into the service layer.

Comment: @DavidG it's that call I'm trying to avoid in my controller all together ;P

Comment: But what happens if the group doesn't exist? You should return a 404 or some indication of that to the user.

Comment: @DavidG In that case I'd expect the object to be null, or the "intercepter" to preferably just return 404 before reaching the controller action all together.

Comment: Then you're hiding away functionality in the interceptor, it starts to get really confusing for devs to understand what is going on. I don't understand why putting the code in an interceptor is any better than putting it in a controller/service.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using an attribute either if that makes the code more readable.

Comment: I think actionfilter is a good choice,here is  [the newest official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-filters),you can use ActionFilterAttribute,and return result with statuscode and data

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom model binder for the class `Group` that retrieves data from the database:

```
public class GroupModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // ************************************************
        // Replace with your code for retrieve group from db
        // ************************************************
        var group = new Group { Name = "Bound Group", Description = "Bound group from custom model binder" };

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(group);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

To use the model binder you simply have to create a custom model binder provider that returns the model binder for type `Group`:

```
public class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Group))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(GroupModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And add it in the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup`:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider());
});
```